# Can't add system("exit"); in C

Tags: c, system, exit

I would like to exit my program with

```
system("exit");
```

in C.
I compiled my code with gcc and run it via terminal. But somehow the program didn't execute the call to the system to exit. Why is that happened? Because if I did `system("clear")` it work smoothly

Comment: can you paste your code lines ?

Comment: @YasarIslam I'm sorry I can't, it's very long, since what I want just this snippets :)

Comment: C11 should really have removed `system` at the same time it removed `gets`. It's equally useless and almost as impossible to use safely.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In C, `system()` starts a shell and executes the command.  `exit` exits the shell.  The expected result would be that nothing happens, what result did you get?

I think what you want is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

Comment: My program keep running, I use this in while loop. Actually I made some kind of dbms mockup, and when i say "good bye" the system must exit, but when I use system("exit") it just keep running.

Anyway, when I use your code it worked, but didn't close the terminal :)

Comment: You can't close the terminal from a program you called, unless you call it with `exec`, in which case exiting normally will close the terminal.

Answer (score 9):

You should just do:

```
exit(0);
```

Also at the top, put:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Answer (score 5):

`system("exit")` won't accomplish anything, since the `system` function simply hands the argument to a command interpreter (I think `sh` on most systems?) This means you're simply creating a new shell and then telling it to immediately quit.

EDIT: as others have said, if the intention is to cause your program to terminate, use the `exit` function found in the stdlib.h header.

Answer (score 2):

Exit isn't a shell command call, it's a c library call. So it'll exit the shell, but not the program. Try:

```
exit(0);
```

Or exit with whatever error code you want.

Answer (score 1):

Why use `system("exit")`? just use `exit(int code);`

`system("exit")` does not exist

Comment: system("exit"); will do something.

Comment: @Alex actually I'm still curious what it do :)

Comment: it'll do something, it just won't be visible.

Comment: **It will do something** what a great answer!! Instead of down-voting, at least give a link to where it says system("exit") does something because I couldn't find it

Comment: Why wouldn't it do something? `system` will spawn a command interpreter, it will interpret the command "exit" and so immediately exit.

Comment: @barrucadu so i can write **system("play")** and **system will spawn a command interpreter, it will interpret the command "play" and so immediately play**

Comment: some libc (ie: glibc) have `system` implemented: http://linux.die.net/man/3/system so it will call `fork` to create a new process and will immediately call `exec` with `${SHELL}` and run the command. `exit` terminates the shell.

Comment: @AhmedAeonAxan Thanks! me neither. After all the chosen answer is the same as mine ..

Answer (score 0):

To exit your program, all you need is an `exit()` call. The `exit()` function causes normal process termination. The  use of `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE` as arguments to `exit()` is slightly more portable (to non-Unix environments) than the use of `0` and some nonzero value like `1` or `-1`. To use `exit()` function, you need to `#include <stdlib.h>`.

More information on `exit()` can be found using `man 3 exit`